# How to know the actual client Height without any JQuery Lib?

Tags: javascript

I find the document.body.clientWidth can be used as the actual client Width even there is nothing display in the window. If you zoom the window, the value will change dynamic.
But if there is nothing displayed in the window, how can I know the actual client Height in case of not using any JQuery Libs?
my code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>
</title>
<style type="text/css">
body
{ 
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    border:0px;
/*    border-color:#FEFEFE;*/
/*    background-image:url(bg.png);*/
    background-repeat: repeat;
    display:block;
    z-index:-9999;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
div
{
    background-color:#a0a0a0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;
    z-index:-8888;
}
</style>
</head>

<body id="body">
<div id="bg">
<span id="s1">
test
</span>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d) {
        setInterval(function () {
            w = d.body.clientWidth;
            document.title = w;
        }, 1);
    })(document)
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i guess you would have to trust innerHeight at that point in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***window.innerHeight*** like the following:

```
var intViewportHeight = window.innerHeight;
```

According [Mozilla MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.innerHeight): window.innerHeight retrieves Height (in pixels) of the browser window viewport including, if rendered, the horizontal scrollbar.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JW5HYdVuGgLMThUW9TcI?p=preview) example.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: No - I'm just asking him to try this solution

Comment: Sorry I don't get it yet - shouldn't I suppose to give him an answer? it's not a thing that i suspect if it will work or not, it's the code that will solve his problem. hmm, maybe i am wrong in the way i offering him the solution?

Comment: "have you tried" implies you aren't sure it will work. If you believe this is the correct answer give add some more resources or a working example to confirm it.